# How to unsubscribe from RxJs subject within an Angular functional route guard

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-router, angular-router-guards

I have a simple Angular **functional** route guard that retrieves a `boolean` value from a `Subject<boolean>` property on a service. The guard seems to work as expected and looks like this:

```js
export const isConfigValidGuard = () => {
  const configService = inject(ConfigService);
  const notificationService = inject(NotificationService);
  const router = inject(Router);

  configService.configValidation$.subscribe({
    next: (isValid) => {
      if (isValid) {
        return true;
      } else {
        notificationService.warn('invalid config, redirecting to home');
        return router.parseUrl('/home');
      }
    }
  });
};
```

My question is do I need to unsubscribe the subscription to `configService.configValidation$` and, if so, how. Again, the type of `configService.configValidation$` is `Subject<boolean>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to unsubscribe or `take(1)` in order to prevent memory leaks.

You could also avoid manual subscription and let Angular handle it for you by returning directly an `Observable`!

```js
export const isConfigValidGuard = () => {
  const configService = inject(ConfigService);
  const notificationService = inject(NotificationService);
  const router = inject(Router);

  configService.configValidation$.pipe(
    map((isValid) => {
      if (isValid) {
        return true;
      } else {
        notificationService.warn('invalid config, redirecting to home');
        return router.parseUrl('/home');
      }
    })
  );
};
```

Since the `Subject` already contains a `boolean` we can return its value, and handle only the case where it is `false`.